# Am I soft-locked right now?

Tags: noita

I have defeated the boss, completed the tower, and completed The Work at the sky altar.  But, unlike the normal ending, you survive this.  I now have no way to kill myself (that I know of) and get the end screen.  I can't blow myself up, I have explosion immunity.  I tried using acid trail on myself, but the acid just turns to gold the instant it leaves my wand.  I tried drowning myself, but all the water on the map is gold now and I collect it so fast it doesn't suffocate me.  I checked the lava lake, and that's all gold now too.

Am I stuck?

Edit: An update deleted my save, so I'm not stuck anymore.  But I don't see any reason why this situation wouldn't happen again.

Comment: I think you're supposed to start a new game in the Esc menu.